# String parsing - replace each repeated occurrence of a substring with a unique replacement

Tags: php, string, parsing

I am trying to parse a string. The catch is each of the variables in the string may occur more than once, and I need to replace each repeated occurrence with a unique replacement.

example `$string = "$Pronoun $Adjective $Noun is as $Adjective as an $Adjective $Noun"`

I've tried `str_replace("$Pronoun", getRandomWordByType('Pronoun'), $string)`

This works apart from the fact that each occurrence of "`$Pronoun`" gets replaced with the same pronoun retrieved from a single call to my `getRandomWordByType('Pronoun')` method.

My objective is to build interesting sentences dynamically, replacing placeholders with words retrieved from a database of words, that are categorised by type...

Thanks in advance for any suggestions :)

Comment: Well to solve this we would like to have more domain knowledge, such as what is the objective and what resources are available. Else this is just a logical programming where you as a programmer need to create rules and your program has to follow those rules to create those sentences. By rules I mean constraints etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
preg_replace_callback("(\$([a-z]+))i",function($a) {return getRandomWordByType($a[1]);},$string);
```

This will automatically convert any keyword of the form `$Something` by passing `Something` to the `getRandomWordByType` function. Another advantage is that the random word function is called once for each word.

To prevent accidental replacements, for example `$NotAKeyword`, have `getRandomWordByType` return `'$'.$keyword` (where `$keyword` is the function's argument) if it can't find the keyword in the valid list.

Comment: Excellent thanks that worked a treat.

Just had to modify the regex pattern slightly for it to work - '|\$([a-z]+)|i'

Thanks!